# Suggestion: Add link to relevant page in "off-topic" notification

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, scope

Pretty minor suggestion, but it could be of some use.

A question of mine, https://askubuntu.com/questions/295699/the-vpn-service-failed-to-start-under-ubuntu-13-04,  was put on hold (at my request) as being off-topic (the reasons are on the page, but to summarise: I'd made a silly mistake and the problem pretty much solved itself - but it was still getting answers long after I'd mentioned that the problem was gone). The offtopic notice reads as follows:

- This question does not appear to be about Ubuntu, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help).

However, "Help center" here links to the help centre's home page, rather than the page on what is actually on-topic. The relevant page requires a little digging to find - not much, granted, but I would say that if it mentions the scope it ought to link to the page that says what the scope is. So, for example:

- This question does not appear to be about Ubuntu, within [the scope defined in the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

In this context (to me at least) this seems like a far more useful place to refer to.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fair point. I've edited the message to point to the [/help/on-topic/](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: Great, thanks! =)